# Json Schema generation from Json data

Tags: c#, xml, json, json.net

Is there any way to generate json schema from json string using Json.net in C#.
My concern is 
Json string:

```
 {"Employees":{"Employee":[{"Fname","Lname","Age"}]}}
```

Consider this as Json data when convert to xml it will be like

```
<Employees>
  <Employee>
   <Fname/>
   <Lname/>
   <Age/>
 </Employee>
```

After doing some operations on xml and if I convert back to Json it will become like this

```
 {"Employees":{"Employee":{"Fname","Lname","Age"}}}
```

The array property of Json will be changed if there is only on array element.
How to resolve this?

Comment: Can you create a Employees Class?

Comment: Actually this JSON `{"Fname","Lname","Age"}` is invalid. Or it's made like that to show the main structure?